# notify-osd and dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, notify-osd

I use Ubuntu 10.10 on a laptop, with an external monitor, which is used as the primary. Notify-osd alerts show on the connected monitor, as I want.

However, some days ago I removed both gnome panels and installed AWN. All was good, but notify-osd alerts now appears on the laptop. I need, that notify-osd appears on the connected monitor.

How can I move notify-osd alerts on the connected monitor without gnome panels?

Comment: Did you set the external monitor as primary?

Answer (score 17):

`gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd multihead-mode focus-follow`

This is the correct way for 12.10.  You can test with `notify-send`

Comment: This will work on 13.04 Unity

Answer (score 14):

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/notify-osd/multihead_mode focus-follow
```

Should display notices on the currently active monitor.

Comment: are there other options besides focus-follow? what if I wanted to pick a specific montior to show notifications on?

Comment: You can use gconf-editor ( dconf-editor on 11.10 ) to see all available options.

Comment: Setting this value doesn't seem to have any effect in 12.10. I did a quick search in dconf and there doesn't seem to be a notify-osd node.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm interesting, it should show up on Primary screen by default and we can choose the monitor in shell like this  `DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "hi"` and `DISPLAY=:1 notify-send "hi"`

Comment: As far as I know, the `DISPLAY` option has nothing to do with multiple monitors. Testing this on Ubuntu 12.04 (with `focus-follow` set as described above), it doesn't seem to do what you suggest either.

Comment: Used to work for me earlier but not using the same setup anymore.