# How can I make notifications appear on a specific monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, notification, notify-osd

In my Ubuntu 12.04, I have two monitors: left is the laptop and the right one is an external and big monitor. My vision is generally focused on the laptop monitor, but the notifications appears in the right one, therefore, I lose the notifications.

Is possible to change the location of the notifications? For example, the notifications appear on the top-right corner of the *laptop/left* monitor.

Comment: Duplicate question, see possible answers in:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/33140/notify-osd-and-dual-monitors

Comment: It is not the answer. Indeed, it is the opposite thing that I want. I want to show the notifications in my laptop and not on the external monitor.

Answer (score 23):

For an imperfect workaround, install **dconf-editor** (provided by the package **dconf-tools**), navigate to **Apps > notify-osd** and change the value of **multihead mode** to **focus-follow**.

This will draw the volume notifications a little too high up on your left monitor, causing them to overlap the panel - but they will at least be drawn on your left monitor. Email/message/music/other notifications don't overlap and look fine using this method.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I am a happy man now :).

Answer (score 5):

It is currently not possible to change the location of the notifications. By the design they should appear in top-right corner of your primary screen, but because of this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/331369

they will always appear on your most right monitor.

There used to be a patch to notify-osd by Roman (Leolik) Sukochev that allowed user to change behaviour of notification, but it was not ported to 12.04 yet.

Right now you can only wait for bug to be fixed or for new version of Leolik's patch or you can set your laptop monitor to be on right side.

ALSO: it does not matter in this case if your monitor is 'laptop' or external, so your question is a duplicate of: [notify-osd and dual monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33140/notify-osd-and-dual-monitors) as stated by user59621.

Comment: I read about the patch of Leolik, but I think this patch is not the solution because this patch only allows a user to choose the location inside of *one* screen, and not allowing to choose the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for installing the patch mentioned above on 12.04 are available in this thread: [How to customize on screen notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/128474/53074) and there is a setting in it for positioning labeled "dynamic" which I found fixed this problem. However, I did not like the way it altered the color and styling of the notifications, so I undid those changes and then used the dconf solution mentioned in a comment in this thread, which I found works pretty well. The slight differences in positioning are a bit annoying though. Hopefully they can fix this soon, as it is quite frustrating.