# Why hasn't ubuntu made notify-osd more configurable yet?

Tags: notify-osd, 12.10, dualhead

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)
>   [notify-osd and dual monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33140/notify-osd-and-dual-monitors)

First thing I fix generally on Ubuntu was the notify-osd in recent releases - it really irritates me that on a dual-monitor, it shows up to the right.  I just dual booted it along side kubuntu and found this still to be the case

Why is it that there's been a PPA to fix/patch notify-osd for years, but it's still not something added to notify-osd out-of-the-box?

---

Further edit below for the daft commentary and the obvious support for it... hopefully it'll get a few (constructive) answers and less comments.

---

I have a dual-monitor setup, 2x 24" 1080p monitors.  When I work on the left-side of the left monitor, the notifications appear on the top right of the right-hand monitor.  That's literally outside my field of view, as my monitor is only about 1.5 ft away from my eyes, and the distance from where my focus is to where the notification appears is over 3 feet.

Comment: [Issues with next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1)](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask) is considered off-topic on the site.

Comment: @anwar - I think you're too quick to (possibly downvote and) strike it down because I mentioned quantal in the title.  The issue is present for some time and requires an outside patch to fix, and I also want to know why that is.

Comment: As for downvote.. really?  because hidden behind a "read more" link in the faq it says I can't ask for a beta.. from what I further read, not a valid downvote, if it makes people feel better about my question, I've reworded it :)

Comment: Because it gets the job done what else do you need from a notification bubble?.

Comment: By the way your Title indicates you want features in notify-osd while your question indicates you have **issues** with it, they're different things, which one is it?.

Comment: @sandroid OK. there is no downvote!

Comment: @UriHerrera if it's all the way on the right of the right monitor while I'm working on the left of the left monitor (like right now actually) it's completely out of my field of view.  Does that get the job done?  I have an issue with the fact it's not configurable.

Comment: You just come across as ranting. If the option isn't already there, it just means it is by design or the developers don't have the time to make it configurable yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [notify-osd and dual monitors](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33140/notify-osd-and-dual-monitors) and [How can I make notifications appear on a specific monitor?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130124/how-can-i-make-notifications-appear-on-a-specific-monitor)