# Change notification popup monitor

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [notify-osd and dual monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33140/notify-osd-and-dual-monitors)

I have two monitors setup currently however when I get a new notification (ie popup for new mail, or im) it fades in on the secondary monitor and fades out on the secondary monitor.

Is there any way to change it so that the notification alerts appear on the primary not secondary monitor?

I'm using a ATI card if that even makes a difference :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the notification work properly on the primary monitor. You may need to update the scema-key `notifyosd` under `com.canonical`

Open a terminal and use the command below:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd multihead-mode "focus-follow"
```

or alternatively, if you have `dconf-tools` installed then :-

- Open `dconf-editor` and
- Navigate to **apps** → **notify-osd** → **multihead-mode** and change the value to **focus-follow**.

  By setting this you can make the notification bubble appear on the display which currently has focus.

To have `dconf-editor`, use command `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` in a terminal or click the link here → [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools].

Comment: Can you make it just appear in a specific monitor rather than focus follow? Also is there docs for this setting anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunatley this doesn't appear to work :| error is sudo `gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd multihead_mode "focus-follow"`
`No such key 'multihead_mode'`

Comment: Check this [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/331369/) and see comment #13

Comment: Your problem is that the key is called `multihead-mode` not `multihead_mode`.  I don't think schemas use underscore characters

Comment: This appears to be working now, its still a bit buggy (the notification overlaps the status bar unlike in single monitor mode), but I'm hoping that will be solved over time. I also used dconf instead of gconf (since gconf doesn't show the key).