# How can I get desktop notifications to display on both screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, notification, notify-send

I have a laptop and a secondary screen that I use for most of my work. When notifications are displayed, they are only on the laptop screen. How can I get it to display on both screens?

*Ubuntu 13.04*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best what you can do for the moment is to make that the notification position to follow the mouse-focus. You can do this from [**dconf Editor**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/): go to **apps** → **notify-osd** and change the value of **multihead mode** to `focus-follow`.

You can see also:

- [How to customize on screen notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications)
- [notify-osd and dual monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33140/notify-osd-and-dual-monitors)

Comment: Thanks. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/252384/16545) on your second link was actually what worker for me because in 13.04 I don't have the `notify-osd` app.

Comment: The `dconf Editor` link is broken and takes you to some commercial site ...

Comment: How to perform the above in `ubuntu 18.04` as the above config path is missing in dconf editor