# How can I get desktop notifications to display on both screens in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, notification

I use Ubuntu 22.04 a laptop connected to an external monitor and use both the integrated display and said monitor for work, switching back and forth between them depending on which programs I need to work with. But I often overlook push notifications from Microsoft Teams if they appear on a different display than the one I'm focused on. Notmally MS teams also makes a sound when a new message is received, but I turned those off because I found them annoying and painfully loud at times.

Is there a way for me to make those push notifications from Microsoft Teams appear on all connected screens, or at least always on the one my cursor is currently on, in Ubuntu 22.04?

The only solutions I found seem to be outdated and no longer apply, such as this one from ten years ago: https://askubuntu.com/a/353113/1138711